# Why does a sum of outer measures of nonmeasurable sets equal infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a nonmeasurable subset of $[0,1]$ whose rational translations, $E_1, E_2, ..., E_k,...$, are disjoint. Consider the translations of $E$ by rational numbers $r$, $0<r<1$, why does $\sum m^*(E_k) = +\infty$? Why the series cannot be convergent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lebesgue outer measure is invariant under translation.  So all the terms $m^*(E_k)$ are equal.  And since $E$ is not measurable, $m^*(E) > 0$.  So in the series, all terms are the same positive number.

Comment: As your argument shows, the disjointness hypothesis seems unnecessary for the purpose of proving an infinite sum.